# Cant get jQuery( html, props ) work with events

Tags: jquery

I am unable to get the click event to work for elements created thusly.

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/PEZXa/

jQuery

```
$('<a href="#">a</a>', {
  click: function(){
    alert('a clicked');
  }
}).appendTo("div");

$('<span>span</span>', {
  click: function(){
    alert('span clicked');
  }
}).appendTo("div");
```

**Please don't show me the 50 different ways you can add an `onclick` event to an element I want to know why this particular method does or does not work.**

From the docs:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @Roko yup, but it's one that _can_ be added using `jQuery(html, props)`

Comment: @Roko in this case it is a key in an object. Please RTFM. Link above.

Comment: @Roko and in jQuery 1.8+ the props can include the name of _any_ jQuery function, not just those previously listed in `$.attrFn`

Comment: I hate asking why the down vote? After all my name is...

Comment: It's probably for not reading the very docs that you linked to, which do specifically state that you must supply a single bare tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('<a />', {
    href: '#',
    text: 'a',
  'click': function(){
    alert('a clicked');
  }
}).appendTo("div");

$('<span />', {
    text: 'span',
  'click': function(){
    alert('span clicked');
  }
}).appendTo("div");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PEZXa/56/

From the docs

> html - A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g. <div/> or <div></div>).

Comment: RTFM :P, can only be `<div/>` or `<div></div>`.  No inner HTML or attributes

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame You're providing an HTML string representing more than 1 empty element. In this case, a DOM parser is invoked. When you pass a string representing a single element, that is `<div>`/`<div/>`/`<div></div>`, all of these are matched as `div` by a regex ran in the jQuery selector and invokes a `document.createElement` on it with the properties you specified. tl;dr: more than 1 empty element string is parsed differently than a more complex html string and has different syntax.

Comment: @stevether Oh for craps sake; you got me. Not being able to build my tag out completely almost makes this a pointless feature to me now.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame on the contrary, using this syntax allows you to build (single) complicated elements without using string concatenation.  Concatenation causes problems with quoting and can lead to XSS exploits.

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/): `If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism.`

Comment: @Alnitak Ah yes good point. I won't completely disavow all knowledge now. Nice.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery doesn't seem to like it when elements that are created like this contain text nodes or attributes. In essence, the HTML code you provide should be a single (possibly self-closing) tag.

This is probably because you are using a syntax that expects the attributes to be defined within the object parameter, not mixed between the HTML and the object.

Anyways, this code works for me:

```
$('<a /> ', {
    href: '#',
    text: 'a',
    click: function() {
        alert('a clicked');
    }
}).appendTo("div");

$('<span />', {
    text: 'span',
    click: function() {
        alert('span clicked');
    }
}).appendTo("div");​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PEZXa/60/**

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$('<a/>', {
    href: "#",
    text: 'a',
    click: function(){
        alert('a clicked');
    }
}).appendTo("div");
```

[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PEZXa/57/)

Comment: @Blender it's not a real attribute, it's a pseudo-attribute only usable in the `jQuery(html, props)` method.

Comment: @Alnitak: That's sort of what I mean. I always just used `.text()` to specify the content.

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery(html, props)` only works if `html` is a single bare tag with no other attributes or child elements on it.